# Reinstalling apps after replacing an SD card

Tags: external-sd

I recently had an SD card die in the field.  I've tried everything I know and can't get anything out of it or have it recognised on any reader with any OS, so I'm pretty much resigned to the fact that it's gone. Nothing irreplaceable on it.

I bought  a replacement 8 GB card and now some of my apps don't work. Is the only way to fix them a remove/reinstall or is there some other option, especially a batch repair/update?  I've had some apps update in the normal way, some work, some don't.

Android 2.3.3
HTC Desire HD, Sense 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most apps save their settings and preferences to the internal memory.  However, many apps are written to use the SD Card for some storage as well.  This is usually done to prevent taking up too much space on the (often very limited) internal memory.  For example, many apps with "offline" mode (e.g. news readers) will place downloaded content onto a folder on the SD Card.

Some apps handle disappearance of such cache from the SD Card better than others.  In most cases though, you can get away with clearing the app cache and data via `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` menu, then tapping on the app, and tapping "Clear data" and "Clear cache" buttons, if available.

Uninstall and re-install is a last resort option and should always work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it depends on how that app was using the sd card or if it was installed on it. If the app was moved to the sd card it will probably have to be uninstalled/reinstalled.

Comment: This sounds most reasonable to me. If the app was installed to the SD card and you switched to a new SD card, then the app will no longer work.